# LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "92

Tags: utf8

after updating latex, i get that error. I tried so many way to get rid of but all were futile. Please help me

```
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "92
l.962 speakers’
                bureaus; membership, employment, consultancies, stock
?
```

Comment: is your file actually utf8 encoded?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19984396/2336725 suggests that apostrophe might be slipping in from a Windows-1252 encoding.  Maybe retype that line?

Comment: Ulrike, actually i dont know how to learn whether the file is utf8 encoded or not?

Comment: many editors will show the current encoding and/or offer an option to save in utf-8

Comment: The error message breaks the problematic line to two parts and the reported problem is always at the end of the first part. What do you see here?

Answer (score 5):

Your file is not encoded in UTF-8, but most likely Windows code page 1252.  (Left single quotation mark is "92 in that encoding.) If you’re compiling in PDFLaTeX and don’t know what the encoding is, the package `selinput` can auto-detect it.  You can replace any `inputenc` command you currently have with:

```
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis={ä},
  germandbls={ß},
  Euro={€},
}
```

This detects any encoding that supports Western European languages, and will continue to work if the file is re-encoded.  (For example, TeX.SX will automatically convert any MWE you upload here to UTF-8.)

You might, however, prefer to save your documents as UTF-8.  Some newer tools require it.  Most editors have the option to do that.  Notepad, for example, displays the encoding in the bottom right of the window, and gives you the option to set it when you Save As.

Comment: +1: Never used selinput before, looks helpful.

Comment: One problem with this is: The file containing the input-command for inputting the cp1252-encoded file might itself not be encoded in cp1252, but, e.g., in utf-8. If in the utf-8-encoded file you do `\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä}, germandbls={ß}, Euro={€},}\input{<cp1252-encoded file>}`, LaTeX will assume utf-8-encoding as `ä`, `ß` and `€`are utf-8 encoded. And in the utf-8 encoded file you cannot replace them by the bytes that in cp1252 represent those characters as those bytes in utf-8 denote components of multibyte-characters and thus their standalone-occurrence triggers error-messages.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I don’t think I understand what you believe the failure mode to be. There is no second file “inputting” commands to `selinput`. You put them in the preamble of your source file. If the options to `selinput` display correctly in your editor, the command will work. If you copied over the bytes as UTF08 but save as CP1242, you would see mojibake. i don’t think trying to include a second file in a different encoding would work.

Comment: @UlrichDiez If you’re not able to modify the source at all, you can’t fix the document.

Comment: @Davislor Assume a multifile-project where you have a master-file which is encoded in utf-8 which you are allowed to modify and some inputfile encoded in cp1252 which you are not allowed to modify. In that case `selinput` is of limited use, but in the master-file you can still do `\inputencoding{cp1252}\input{<cp1252-encoded file>}\inputencoding{utf8}`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Also, what the LaTeX kernel has done since 2018 is, if no input encoding has been selected in the preamble, it will load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` by default, before `\begin{document}`. PDFLaTeX does not assume that the preamble is encoded in valid UTF-8.

Comment: @UlrichDiez That seems like an extremely unusual edge case. In that situation, you would need to save all the files in the project in the same encoding. Potentially, if the master file was written before 2018, assumed that the default encoding was OT1, never loaded `inputenc` explicitly, and cannot be modified, what you would need to do to compile it is, write a new master file that runs `\usepackage[OT1]{inputenc}` and then includes the original master file. In that special case, you would not want `selinput`.

Comment: I have many old .tex files, written when cp1252 was en vogue with Windows, and sometimes I wish to input some of them into a new LaTeX document, whose master file is in utf-8. This may be an edge scenario but it is the only scenario known to me where encoding issues leading to `Invalid UTF-8 byte`-errors ever did "bite" me. Then in the utf-8-encoded master-file I do: `\inputencoding{cp1252}\input{<cp1252-encoded file>}\inputencoding{utf8}`. Afaik nowadays LaTeX automatically loads inputenc/utf8 in case after the preamble inputenc was not yet loaded otherwise.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Excuse me, in my example, the new master file would need to call `\RequirePackage` rather than `\usepackage`, because it runs before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Thanks for both of your insights! It was very educational ("lehrreich"). at_Davislor and at_Ulrich.

Comment: @Davislor Why `[OT1]` with inputenc? (Afaik OT1 is a font-encoding, i.e., s.th. for the package `fontenc`.)

Comment: @UlrichDiez All right, I see the use case you’re talking about now. That’s a complex use case I haven’t ever tried to run, and while I think `\SelectInputMappings` within each included file would still work, you might need to do a lot of manual overrides.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I gave the example of a master file written before 2018, which relied on the default input encoding being OT1 instead of UTF-8. To compile that file under a modern LaTeX kernel, you would need to set the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

```
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "92
l.962 speakers’
                bureaus; membership, employment, consultancies, stock
?
```

Maybe the error-message is due to `’` in `speakers’ bureaus`.

Nowadays encoding text-files in utf-8, which is a multi-byte-encoding, is en vogue with many computer platforms. (With a multi-byte-encoding encoding a single character may take several bytes.)

E.g., with legacy Windows platforms encoding text-files in cp1252, which is a single-byte-encoding, was en vogue. (With a single-byte-encoding encoding a single character takes a single byte.)

With nowadays LaTeX the inputenc-package is loaded with option "utf-8" automatically so that by default input-files are assumed to be encoded in utf-8.

(If before updating your LaTeX was very old, then before updating inputenc/utf-8 was not loaded by default.)

Byte Hex92 = Dec146 = Bin 10010010  denotes the right single quotation-mark `’` in the character-encoding-scheme Windows cp1252.

But in the character-encoding-scheme utf-8 that byte is - like every byte whose leading bits are `10` - a non-first byte of a multi-byte-character.

If this byte occurs in a place where a first byte of an utf-8-charcater is expected while processing utf-8, an error-message is raised.

This might happen if an updated LaTeX where inputenc/utf-8 is loaded automatically by default processes a .tex-input-file and hereby (erroneously) assumes that it is encoded in utf-8 while actually it is encoded in cp1252 and contains some single right quotation mark characters.

Probably you can resolve the issue via placing the directive `\inputencoding{cp1252}` from the package inputenc (or whatever the correct encoding is) right before the directive for inputting the file in question.

You may need to switch back to utf-8 via `\inputencoding{utf8}` before processing other `\usepackage`-directives or before processing more content of the file where the directive for loading that file occurred.

Alternatively have the file in question re-encoded in utf-8.

Comment: i reinstall miktex and while installing it gives that warning   "initexmf: warning: The lualatex executable could not be found." may this be reason of the problem